# Executing a SQL command using Entity Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a query like this

```
Select * From Good 
where GoodCode in (Select GoodRef From GoodGroup Where GoodGroupRef=264)
```

In SqlCommand I want to execute it using LINQ. How I can execute command for this SQL command? I don't know what the entity command for it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var ris= dc.ExecuteStoreQuery<goodType>("select * from good where goodcode in (select good ref from goodgroup where goodgroupref=263))");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectContext context;//new ObjectContext 
var goods = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<Good>("your query");
```